# What is the difference between connect by level and connect by prior in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, hierarchical-data, connect-by

Plz any one explain me about "connect by level" and "connect by prior" in oracle with basic example..

qn 1)
select to_date('&fromdate','DD-MM-YYYY') + level -1
from dual
connect by level<=
to_date('&todate','DD-MM-YYYY')-to_date('&fromdate','DD-MM-YYYY')+1;

qn 2)
Plz explain me about connect by prior with a basic query.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to view this link, in the section Hierarchical Query Examples there are some example

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm